# Combo box not recognized string in an if statement

Tags: c#, string, combobox

I'm trying to create a program which determines what string is selected in a combo box and then converts that string into an integer to be used in a calculation. Below is the section of code that's giving me trouble.

All of my combo box strings are returning the error:
class system.String
Represents text as a series of Unicode Characters.
Error:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox'

```
            //Calculate Living Space replacement cost
            int livingSpaceSQ;
            int livingSpaceCostPerSF;
            int livingSpaceCost;

            if (cmbConstructionQuality = "Basic")
            {
                livingSpaceCostPerSF = 170;
            }
            if (cmbConstructionQuality = "Standard")
            {
                livingSpaceCostPerSF = 185;
            }
            if (cmbConstructionQuality = "Semi-Custom")
            {
                livingSpaceCostPerSF = 195;
            }
            else
            {
                livingSpaceCostPerSF = 225;
            }
            livingSpaceSQ = int.Parse(txtBuiltInGarage.Text.ToString());
            livingSpaceCost = livingSpaceSQ * livingSpaceCostPerSF;
            txtLivingSpaceCost.Text = livingSpaceCost.ToString();
```

I'm not really sure what that means. How would I make this work as to convert the selected string into an integer?

Comment: Note that a single `=` is an assignment operator, it is **NOT** a comparison operator. Otherwise, look at @cahinton's answer for a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
    if (cmbConstructionQuality.Text == "Basic")
    {
        livingSpaceCostPerSF = 170;
    }
```

and replace the `=` in your if statements with `==`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with cmbConstructionQuality.Text property

Also write the if statements like this:

```
        if (cmbConstructionQuality.Text == "Basic")
        {
            livingSpaceCostPerSF = 170;
        }
        else if (cmbConstructionQuality.Text =="Standard")
        {
            livingSpaceCostPerSF = 185;
        }
        else if (cmbConstructionQuality.Text == "Semi-Custom")
        {
            livingSpaceCostPerSF = 195;
        }
        else
        {
            livingSpaceCostPerSF = 225;
        }
```

In this case when you hit one of the if, you will not check the others.